# Bootstrap Treeview with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, django, treeview

Can anyone help me convert this PHP code to the Django code?

I want to use Bootstrap Treeview Plugin with dynamic data coming from Django backend. I fount this code from a website but unfortunately it is for PHP.
And I don't even know the "P" of PHP.

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing1");
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM country_state_city
";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
//$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_data["id"] = $row["id"];
 $sub_data["name"] = $row["name"];
 $sub_data["text"] = $row["name"];
 $sub_data["parent_id"] = $row["parent_id"];
 $data[] = $sub_data;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 $output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
 {
  $output[$value["parent_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
 }
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
 {
  unset($data[$key]);
 }
}
echo json_encode($data);
/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';*/

?>
```

This is the table structure they used in the tutorial for PHP.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `country_state_city`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country_state_city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `country_state_city`
--

INSERT INTO `country_state_city` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 'USA', 0),
(2, 'Canada', 0),
(3, 'Australia', 0),
(4, 'New York', 1),
(5, 'Alabama', 1),
(6, 'California', 1),
(7, 'Ontario', 2),
(8, 'British Columbia', 2),
(9, 'New South Wales', 3),
(10, 'Queensland', 3)

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `country_state_city`
--
ALTER TABLE `country_state_city`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `country_state_city`
--
ALTER TABLE `country_state_city`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=28;
```

Comment: Proper username.

Comment: @kerbh0lz What?